# Are there ways to change a numpy value by chance?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to change an element in a numpy array by chances so it looks like this :

```
arr = np.random.randint(1,9, data_length).astype(str)
arr[arr == "1"] = "1" if random.randint(1,2) == 1 else "A"

# result should be 1 would have a 50% chance of becoming an "A"
```

For some reason, this does not work, the actual result is :

```
>>> arr
array(['1', '3', '5', '7', '3', '7', '3', '4', '2', '4', '5', '5', '5',
       '2', '8', '4', '1', '1', '6', '7', '3', '6', '6', '1', '2', '2',
       '8', '1', '1', '2', '3', '6', '7', '6', '4', '3', '3', '7', '3',
       '6', '5', '3', '7', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '6', '2', '4', '7',
       '3', '6', '3', '3', '7', '1', '6', '6', '8', '6', '4', '5', '3',
       '3', '6', '8', '8', '3', '1', '7', '7', '8', '8', '3', '7', '4',
       '2', '3', '2', '5', '1', '3', '1', '8', '5', '4', '3', '8', '1',
       '1', '2', '5', '2', '2', '5', '1', '2', '4', '3', '4', '2', '7',
       '4', '8', '7', '8', '3', '7', '7', '8', '1', '1', '6', '2', '8',
       '6', '1', '5', '2', '6', '3', '1', '3', '5', '7', '4', '8', '1',
       '8', '1', '7', '5', '3', '7', '5', '5', '8', '6', '2', '6', '4',
       '7', '1', '3', '4', '5', '7', '7', '2', '8', '2', '5', '7', '3',
       '3', '7', '5', '2', '1', '5', '5', '2', '6', '4', '3', '8', '2',
       '8', '5', '8', '8', '1', '2', '4', '4', '1', '8', '2', '5', '5',
       '2', '3', '4', '2', '6', '3', '1', '8', '2', '5', '8', '8', '3',
       '1', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '2', '5', '5', '5', '3', '7', '1',
       '5', '6', '5', '4', '3', '5', '8', '7', '2', '7', '2', '2', '1',
       '7', '4', '7', '3', '5', '4', '3', '8', '6', '1', '1', '7', '5',
       '1', '8', '6', '3', '1', '3', '6', '2', '3', '7', '4', '6', '5',
       '7', '1', '6', '4', '5', '6', '2', '2', '6', '7', '3', '1', '7',
       '6', '5', '6', '3', '4', '2', '4', '3', '1', '5', '6', '4', '5',
       '7', '2', '6', '3', '8', '3', '7', '1', '3', '3', '6', '4', '5',
       '3', '5', '4', '7', '4', '2', '5', '7', '4', '6', '8', '6', '6',
       '3'], dtype='<U21')
```

And I am very certain that random.randint(1,2) gives 1 or 2, so I am confused why there are no changes at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you generated only one value:

```
>>> '1' if random.randint(1, 2) == 1 else 'A'
'1'
```

And you use this value to assign to the position where the element in `arr` is `'1'`. This will not make 50% of `'1'` become `'A'`, but there is a 50% probability that all `'1'` become `'A'`.

The correct way is to generate an array with the length of `'1'` occurrence times, where `'1'` and `'A'` are randomly generated, and then this array is used for assignment:

```
>>> mask = arr == '1'
>>> arr[mask] = np.random.default_rng().choice(('1', 'A'), mask.sum())
>>> # The speed of choice is relatively slow. The faster way is
>>> # arr[mask] = np.where(np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 2, mask.sum(), bool))
>>> arr
array(['A', '3', '5', '7', '3', '7', '3', '4', '2', '4', '5', '5', '5',
       '2', '8', '4', '1', '1', '6', '7', '3', '6', '6', 'A', '2', '2',
       '8', 'A', 'A', '2', '3', '6', '7', '6', '4', '3', '3', '7', '3',
       '6', '5', '3', '7', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '6', '2', '4', '7',
       '3', '6', '3', '3', '7', 'A', '6', '6', '8', '6', '4', '5', '3',
       '3', '6', '8', '8', '3', '1', '7', '7', '8', '8', '3', '7', '4',
       '2', '3', '2', '5', 'A', '3', 'A', '8', '5', '4', '3', '8', '1',
       'A', '2', '5', '2', '2', '5', '1', '2', '4', '3', '4', '2', '7',
       '4', '8', '7', '8', '3', '7', '7', '8', '1', 'A', '6', '2', '8',
       '6', 'A', '5', '2', '6', '3', '1', '3', '5', '7', '4', '8', '1',
       '8', 'A', '7', '5', '3', '7', '5', '5', '8', '6', '2', '6', '4',
       '7', 'A', '3', '4', '5', '7', '7', '2', '8', '2', '5', '7', '3',
       '3', '7', '5', '2', '1', '5', '5', '2', '6', '4', '3', '8', '2',
       '8', '5', '8', '8', 'A', '2', '4', '4', '1', '8', '2', '5', '5',
       '2', '3', '4', '2', '6', '3', '1', '8', '2', '5', '8', '8', '3',
       '1', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '2', '5', '5', '5', '3', '7', '1',
       '5', '6', '5', '4', '3', '5', '8', '7', '2', '7', '2', '2', 'A',
       '7', '4', '7', '3', '5', '4', '3', '8', '6', 'A', '1', '7', '5',
       '1', '8', '6', '3', 'A', '3', '6', '2', '3', '7', '4', '6', '5',
       '7', '1', '6', '4', '5', '6', '2', '2', '6', '7', '3', '1', '7',
       '6', '5', '6', '3', '4', '2', '4', '3', 'A', '5', '6', '4', '5',
       '7', '2', '6', '3', '8', '3', '7', '1', '3', '3', '6', '4', '5',
       '3', '5', '4', '7', '4', '2', '5', '7', '4', '6', '8', '6', '6',
       '3'], dtype='<U21')
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `random.randint` should instead be `np.random.randint` on line 2.

Secondly, if you read the [documentation of randint](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html), you will find that the second parameter is *one above the largest (signed) integer to be drawn from the distribution*. As such, if you want to produce a random integer out of 1 and 2, your implementation should be `np.random.randint(1,3)`.